# Is there a replacement of NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX (Hashi) env variable in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, hashicorp

In, nomad, we have an env variable named NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX, that gives me the index of the container, is there a similar env variable in Kubernetes for the pods to get the pod index?

Could you please provide your inputs?

Thanks,
Sarita

Answer (score 2):

Not really, unless you are using [indexed jobs (Kubernetes 1.21, Apr. 2021)](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/19/introducing-indexed-jobs/).

For indexed jobs,  the index is exposed to each Pod in the `batch.kubernetes.io/job-completion-index` annotation and the `JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX` environment variable.

Official documentation: "**[Indexed Job for Parallel Processing with Static Work Assignment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/indexed-parallel-processing-static/)**"

You can use the builtin `JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX` environment variable set by the Job controller for all containers.
Optionally, you can [define your own environment variable through the downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to publish the index to containers

---

There is also [`kubernetes/enhancements` PR2630](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/2630/files), where the Pods hostname are set to `$(job-name)-$(index)`.

This is not yet integrated to Kubernetes, but could means you can derive the pod hostname from the job name and index, allowing you to get its IP. That means pods can address each other with a DNS lookup and communicate directly using Pod IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a k8s deployment as follows:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-5b567ff889-qgw2t   1/1     Running   0          92s
nginx-deployment-5b567ff889-r2rxc   1/1     Running   0          91s
```

The last unique identifiers there (`qgw2t` and `r2rxc`) are pod identifiers which is analogous to job group in Nomad.  Tasks refer to the containers within the group (or containers in Pod).  Most pods are a single container, just like how most Nomad job groups contain only one task.  The `NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX` is an identifier for the task, meaning the k8s equivalent here is the unique identifier for the container.  In which case, you can find with (for my example above):

```
kubectl get pods nginx-deployment-5b567ff889-qgw2t -o json | jq -r '.status.containerStatuses[].containerID'
```

which wil produce an output like:

```
containerd://79092fc5a78852c73bffc7b4a3582f92cd4b5d6b5c1da8c334fbe2507345b6bf
```

If you want you can pipe that to something that will remove the `containerd://` piece.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** I misread the docs, it's the index of task groups (not just tasks). So I guess the identifier you're looking for here is the pod identifiers (in my example above, it'd be the qgw2t and r2rxc). But it still wouldn't give you what you're looking for as there's no contiguous counter for the pods.

When you update your Nomad jobs, however, it's able to maintain the same indices becuase it stops the old right before it starts up the new, where as for k8s, it spins up a new one and ensure it is healthy before terminating the old one.

Comment: While this is true at an abstract level it does not meet the real world constraints for NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX.
NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX is a 0 based contiguous range. e.g. our services are typically scaled from 2-20 so there is always NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX 0 and 1 and MAYBE 2-19.
NOMAD_ALLOC_INDEX is used for things like logging and metrics keys. e.g. influxdb series key. Allowing any arbitrary value here causes influxdb cardinality problems. Hence the need for a zero based, contiguous index.

Comment: Actually, I totally misread the docs, it's the index of task groups (not just tasks).  So I guess the identifier you're looking for here is the pod identifiers (in my example above, it'd be the `qgw2t` and `r2rxc`).  But it still wouldn't give you what you're looking for as there's no contiguous counter for the pods.  

When you update your Nomad jobs, however, it's able to maintain the same indices  becuase it stops the old right before it starts up the new, where as for k8s, it spins up a new one and ensure it is healthy before terminating the old one.